# using unicode dlls in MBCS projects or vice versa

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dll, unicode

I have a vc++ dll that is compiled with charset set to 'Use Unicode Character Set'.
Now i want to use this dll in my vc++ exe whose charset is 'Use Multi-Byte Character Set'. I know that theoretically nothing stops me from doing this as after compiling the vc++ dll, all the function signatures would be either wchar_t or LPCWSTRs .. And in my vc++ exe i just create strings of that format and call the exported functions. But, The problem i am facing is , The header in unicode dll takes TCHAR parameters like for ex:

```
class MYLIBRARY_EXPORT PrintableInt
{
public:
    PrintableInt(int value);
    ...
    void PrintString(TCHAR* somestr);

private:
   int m_val;
};
```

Now i want to use this PrintString() in my exe. So, I included the header and used it like below:

```
#include "unicodeDllHeaders.h"
PrintableInt p(2);
wchar_t* someStr = L"Some str";
p.PrintString(someStr);
```

This as expected gives me a compiler error :

```
error C2664: 'PrintableInt::PrintString' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'wchar_t *' to 'TCHAR *'
```

As the exe is built with MBCS TCHAR is defined to char . So, what i thought would solve this issue is :

```
#define _UNICODE
#include "unicodeDllHeaders.h"
#undef _UNICODE
```

But after defining _UNICODE also i still get the compilation error. So, my next guess was that probably TCHAR.h  was already included before the #include "unicodeDllHeaders.h" , when i searched for the inclusion of TCHAR.h it was there else where in the project. So, I moved the inclusion to after definition of _UNICODE , This solved the compilation error here but it is failing in the other places where TCHAR is expected to be made char . So, My question is :

Can i somehow make TCHAR resolve to char and wchar_t in the same project ? I tried #define TCHAR char, #undef TCHAR , #define TCHAR wchar_t but its failing in the c headers like xutils

Answer (score 0):

You can not retroactively change the binary interface of your DLL, regardless of what do to your header file by using macros. The typical solution is to firstly dump the whole legacy MBCS stuff. This stopped being interesting 10 years ago, nowadays all targets supporting the win32 API support the wide character interface with full Unicode support.

If you want that retro feeling of the nineties, you can also compile your DLL twice, once with CHAR and once with WCHAR. The latter then typically get a "u" suffix (for Unicode). In your header, you then check the charset and delegate to the according DLL using `#pragma comment lib..`.

Comment: I understand but i dont have control over the dll . Thats a legacy dll which i cant change. Now, i ended up with a exe which includes two header files where in one header the TCHAR should map to char and in the other TCHAR shall map to wchar_t. Is there any way i could do this?

Comment: Okay, just that I understand you right, you have a single DLL and its header files use `TCHAR`. The problem then is that the header files don't actually describe the binary interface of the DLL, because in the DLL they actually use `WCHAR` or `CHAR`. The solution for that is simple: Fix the header files. Replace all `TCHAR` (and `PTSTR` etc) there with the according declarations that match the DLL interface.

Comment: Ok .. So instead of fixing the way i include the dll headers in my exe , You advise me to modify the dll headers that i have to have concrete types that are actually defined as in the dll like char/wchar_t or LPSTR/LPWSTR ... This must work , and just to get the total picture, Would it be ever possible to fix this in my exe header/source where i include these dll headers to define TCHAR as both char and wchar_t through some #define s like _UNICODE or _TCHAR_DEFINED ?.

Comment: In order to wrap the header in preprocessor macros as a fix, you would have to redefine all `TCHAR` types first, then include the header and then restore the original definition. Also, any headers like `tchar.h` that were included by the DLL header would have to be included first, so that the include guards render prevent their interference. You would have to do that in every place that includes the DLL headers. Also, for maintenance, add an according comment explaining the issue. I'd rather patch the header files though, which is more reliable.